# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages' Pycharm 5.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to make a simple telegram bot that just sends some text back. I am working with Pycharm. 
My program:

```
import time
import telepot

def add(chat_id, msg):
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'add')

def age(chat_id, msg):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'age')

def remove(chat_id, msg):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'remove')

def birthday(chat_id, msg):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'birthday')

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print('Got command: %s' % command)
    print(chat_id)

    if '/birthday' in command:
        birthday(chat_id, msg)
    elif '/add' in command:
        add(chat_id, msg)
    elif '/remove' in command:
        remove(chat_id, msg)
    elif '/age' in command:
        age(chat_id, msg)

bot = telepot.Bot('<My token>')
bot.notifyOnMessage(handle)
print('I am listening ...')

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

If I run my program in a terminal, it works fine, but if I try to run it with Pycharm, this is what I get back.

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/omer/PycharmProjects/RelAgeBot/RelAgeBot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/PycharmProjects/RelAgeBot/RelAgeBot.py", line 17, in <module>
    import telepot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have installed the 'telepot' package with pip on a terminal and again with Pycharm, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you have a module named `requests` somewhere that could be clashing with `telepot` when it tries to import the real `requests`?

Comment: @dursk Yes there is a module called request! I have tried to update it a few times, but I guess I failed somewhere. After I successfully updated request, it worked. Thank you, I'll write an answer:) But how did you know it was that package? I see that something is going wrong with the module requests, but I dont see why.

Comment: @OmerSaker Well, in the stacktrace, the final line it is blowing up on was in the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py`, so I went and looked at the source code here: https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/blob/master/telepot/__init__.py#L5 to verify that in fact the `telepot` package is using `requests`.

Comment: @dursk Thank you, I will look more closely to the stack trace in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, after @dursk commented that the problem may be with the module 'requests', I tried to update it again. I do not know exactly why, but Pycharm did not update this module. After I tried updating it a few times, it was updated. Now it works.

So in Pycharm go to the Settings > Project > Project Interpreter. In this list search for the package you are looking for and dubble click it. Click the option to download a specific version and choose the latest. And then just click install and you are done

Comment: Wow, the same line was giving me a problem: `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` and I just followed the advice to upgrade the `requests` package. I'm running from command line in Ubuntu. I did `sudo pip3 install --upgrade requests` and it fixed my problem. Thanks!